# adding border to flex items in a row aligned to baseline

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**Question:** How can I get a border to stretch to the height of the parent and surround child cell. Given I am using flexbox and aligning to baseline.

Can this be done with all css?

**More Details:**
I am using flex box to align my items in each row to a certain baseline. It is centered on each cell under "center here" in the following picture:

[image: using flexbox centered on "center here"]

When I hover currently on each item it hovers with a solid line with a 10px margin around each cell:

[image: hover]

I want the on hover border to stretch to the top and bottom of the row on hover like this:

[image]

That way when I hover on each item, their hover border boxes would line up like this:

[image]

^ this is what I would like it to look like if I turn hover on, on each cell.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/NickDueber-minted/pen/WGAvBd)

```css
/* on hover i want this to be a box around the item, and to have the top and the bottom of the border be touching the top/bottom of the row it is on */
.flex-item:hover {
  border: 1px solid darkred;
}

/* so item doesn't move when not hovering */
.flex-item {
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
}

.flex-container {
  overflow: hidden;    position: relative;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: baseline;
  align-items: baseline;
  width: 400px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 10px;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.flex-body {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.flex-body-more {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.flex-img {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
      <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="flex-title">flex title1</div>
        <div class="flex-img">
          <img src='http://dummyimage.com/90x40/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-body">center here</div>
        <div class="flex-body-more">more text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="flex-title">flex title1 longer title</div>
        <div class="flex-img">
          <img src='http://dummyimage.com/40x40/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-body">center here</div>
        <div class="flex-body-more">more text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="flex-title">flex title1</div>
        <div class="flex-img">
          <img src='http://dummyimage.com/40x90/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-body">center here</div>
        <div class="flex-body-more">more text more text more text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="flex-title">flex title1</div>
        <div class="flex-img">
          <img src='http://dummyimage.com/90x40/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-body">center here</div>
        <div class="flex-body-more">more text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="flex-title">flex title1</div>
        <div class="flex-img">
          <img src='http://dummyimage.com/40x50/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-body">center here</div>
        <div class="flex-body-more">more text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a few rules that you'll need to adjust to your flex items:

```
.flex-item {
    border: 1px solid lightblue;
    transition: .7s;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.flex-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    width: 400px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 10px;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

**See code snippet below:**

```css
/* on hover i want this to be a box around the item, and to have the top and the bottom of the border be touching the top/bottom of the row it is on */
.flex-item:hover {
  border: 1px solid darkred;
}

/* so item doesn't move when not hovering */
.flex-item {
    border: 1px solid lightblue;
    transition: .7s;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.flex-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    width: 400px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 10px;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.flex-body {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.flex-body-more {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.flex-img {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
      <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="flex-title">flex title1</div>
        <div class="flex-img">
          <img src='http://dummyimage.com/90x40/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-body">center here</div>
        <div class="flex-body-more">more text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="flex-title">flex title1 longer title</div>
        <div class="flex-img">
          <img src='http://dummyimage.com/40x40/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-body">center here</div>
        <div class="flex-body-more">more text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="flex-title">flex title1</div>
        <div class="flex-img">
          <img src='http://dummyimage.com/40x90/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-body">center here</div>
        <div class="flex-body-more">more text more text more text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="flex-title">flex title1</div>
        <div class="flex-img">
          <img src='http://dummyimage.com/90x40/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-body">center here</div>
        <div class="flex-body-more">more text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="flex-title">flex title1</div>
        <div class="flex-img">
          <img src='http://dummyimage.com/40x50/000/ffffff&text=hi'>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-body">center here</div>
        <div class="flex-body-more">more text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is close to what i'm looking for... however i do need to keep the items aligned to their baseline. Aligning items to center violates the premise of the question.

Comment: @duebstep Whoa! Didn't mean to violate the question in anyway :) I know you mentioned "baseline", but I was actually going off your last image as a reference. Have another look at the answer, I've updated it to align the items to the baseline (technically `flex-end`). The tricky part is the "stretching" of the elements in question, the alignment you can play around with by simply adjusting the `align-items` rule on your `.flex-item` class

Comment: I would use those if i could and they centered the items to the line that says "center here"; however it doesn't center them there. it has a different output that centers them at a different point for each item. Thanks for your attempt at it! Let me know if you can think of a work around!

Comment: @duebstep Oh no, problem, and hey, there's is always a work around which one could think of, given enough time. The alignment is not as random as you infer either; they are all baseline, if you need the alignment to reference another anchor point (i.e: `flex-body`) then simply experiment with `flex` styles on different elements until you get your desired end result (you may have to be open to restructuring your html in order to help you get there). I'm sure you'll figure it out though, good luck!